# No applicable action for totalSizeCap in logback spring boot logging

Tags: logging, spring-boot, logback

I am trying to limit maximum number of log files using "totalSizeCap" element from logback. I am using spring boot application, so included logback as follows :

logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true">
    <include resource="log4j/logback-${spring.profiles.active}.xml"/>
</configuration>
```

log4j/logback-DEV.xml

```
included>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/tmp//log/log.out</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/tmp/log/log_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.out</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>1</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>2MB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

    <logger name="com.company" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="ERROR" />

</included>
```

---

*ERROR*

```
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@17:27 - no applicable action for [totalSizeCap], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][rollingPolicy][totalSizeCap]]
```

How I limit the log files?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the `logback.xml` isn't the right place to specify what you want. Instead you should be using the `logback-spring.xml` file. This is due to the fact that the Logback framework is loaded before the ApplicationContext (so that the context can log some initial things) then the context loads the `logback-spring.xml` to change the logback settings for the rest of the time the application is running. As such my guess is that the `${spring.profiles.active}` is not replaced with the active profile.

From the [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html)

> When possible we recommend that you use the `-spring` variants for your
>   logging configuration (for example `logback-spring.xml` rather than
>   `logback.xml`). If you use standard configuration locations, Spring
>   cannot completely control log initialization.

Reading a bit further while answering this question there is a section specifically around [Logback extensions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logback-extensions). It looks like you need to use `<springProperty>` element in the configuration to expose the property.

```
<springProperty scope="context" name="activeProfile" source="spring.profiles.active" defaultValue="DEV"/>
<include resource="log4j/logback-${activeProfile}.xml"/>
```